# How to print the neo4j-queries to the console? (Javascript)

Tags: javascript, http, neo4j

I want to execute this query to print all the records of my local neo4j dataset(MATCH (n) RETURN (n)). Now I just get the String value of 'body' in the console ({"statements":[{"statement":"MATCH (n) RETURN (n)"}]} (15:48:43:830)
  at public_html/index.html:33)

How do I accomplish this?

This is my code:

```
var body = JSON.stringify({
            statements: [{
                statement: 'MATCH (n) RETURN (n)'
            }]
        });
$.ajax({
    url: "http://localhost:7474/db/data/transaction/commit",
    type: "POST",
    data: body,
    dataType: "json",
    contentType: "application/json"


    })

          .done(function(result){
            console.log(body);

        })
        .fail(function(error){
            console.log(error.statusText);
        });

                        </script>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The value of `body` doesn't change after you submit your query, you're getting a string because it is the same string you started with. The server's response is in `result`. It will be an array with two elements, `errors` and `results`. For example, to drill down to a single result, you'd look in `result.results[0].data[0].row[0]`.

```
var body = JSON.stringify({
    statements: [{
        statement: 'MATCH (n) RETURN n'
    }]
});
$.ajax({
    url: "http://localhost:7474/db/data/transaction/commit",
    type: "POST",
    data: body,
    dataType: "json",
    contentType: "application/json"
    })
    .done(function(result){
      console.log(result.results[0].data[0].row[0]);
    })
    .fail(function(error){
      console.log(error.statusText);
    });
```

Just be aware that a Cypher error won't count as a failure as far as JS is concerned. You'll want to take your `result` value and send it to another function for evaluation.